# MySQL PDO count function returning incorrect with multiple WHERE criteria

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

As long as I only specify one item in the WHERE clause, this function works fine. If there's more than one, it always returns 0.

Here's the function:

```
function count_rows($table, $where=array()){
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `$table`";
    if(!empty($where)){
        $sql .= " WHERE (";
        foreach($where as $key=>$value){
            $sql .="`". $key . "`=:w_" . $key . " AND ";
        }
        $sql = substr($sql, 0, -4);
        $sql .= ") ";
    }
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    foreach($where as $key=>$value){
        $stmt->bindParam(":w_".$key, $value);
    }
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute();
    $this->stmt = $stmt; 
    return $this->stmt->fetchColumn();

}
```

For example, the following returns the number of rows where `list_id` is set to $list_id:

```
$email_count = count_rows("emails", array("list_id"=>$list_id));
```

Using two criteria in the WHERE clause, however, causes it to return 0 no matter what:

```
$optout_count = count_rows("emails", array("list_id"=>$list_id, "optout"=>"1"));
```

I've tried with and without the parentheses around the WHERE clause, and the debug function I use shows the query properly. I have also tried putting quotes around the values in the array. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**[PDOStatement::bindParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)** bind a **reference** to a variable. Unlike `PDOStatement::bindValue()`, the variable is **bound as a reference** and will only be evaluated at the time that `PDOStatement::execute()` is called.

---

***Solution:***

Just change

```
$stmt->bindParam(":w_".$key, $value);
```

to

```
$stmt->bindValue(":w_".$key, $value);
```

Comment: Ah I knew it had to be something simple. I made that change in every other one of my database functions except this one. That fixed it- thanks for the help!